# How to set IRQ priority in Linux from C/C++?

Tags: c++, c, linux, system-calls, interrupt

Right now I’m setting an IRQ priority in a real-time Linux using `chrt` (for a given irqPid):

```
/usr/bin/chrt -f -p 95 irqPid
```

Is there a way / some function to do this from C/C++ (other than running `system()` to execute command above)?

Comment: Well as you are talking about linux I am pretty sure there must be chrt source code somewhere, so you just have to copy from that (and be thankful to the people that wrote it).

Comment: https://fossies.org/linux/util-linux/schedutils/chrt.c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want [sched_setattr](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sched_getattr.2.html). Using [strace](https://linux.die.net/man/1/strace) it was fairly simple to see what syscall chrt is using.

```
$ sleep 10 &
[2] 3590
$ sudo strace -- /usr/bin/chrt -f -p 95 $! 2>&1 | grep "=95"
sched_setattr(3590, {size=48, sched_policy=SCHED_FIFO, sched_flags=0, sched_nice=0, sched_priority=95, sched_runtime=0, sched_deadline=0, sched_period=0}, 0) = 0
```

Some code that does this for the current process looks like:

```
#include <sched.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/syscall.h>
#include <unistd.h>

struct sched_attr {
   uint32_t size;              /* Size of this structure */
   uint32_t sched_policy;      /* Policy (SCHED_*) */
   uint64_t sched_flags;       /* Flags */
   int32_t  sched_nice;        /* Nice value (SCHED_OTHER,
                                  SCHED_BATCH) */
   uint32_t sched_priority;    /* Static priority (SCHED_FIFO,
                                  SCHED_RR) */
   /* Remaining fields are for SCHED_DEADLINE */
   uint64_t sched_runtime;
   uint64_t sched_deadline;
   uint64_t sched_period;
};

static int sched_setattr(pid_t pid, const struct sched_attr *attr, unsigned int flags)
{
    return syscall(SYS_sched_setattr, pid, attr, flags);
}

int main(int, char**) {
    int result;
    struct sched_attr attr;
    memset(&attr, 0, sizeof(attr));
    attr.size = sizeof(sched_attr);
    attr.sched_priority = 95;
    attr.sched_policy = SCHED_FIFO;
    result = sched_setattr(getpid(), &attr, 0);
    if (result == -1) {
        perror("Error calling sched_setattr.");
    }
}
```

Using strace again on the compiled file:

```
$ sudo strace ./a.out 2>&1 | grep "=95"
sched_setattr(4889, {size=48, sched_policy=SCHED_FIFO, sched_flags=0, sched_nice=0, sched_priority=95, sched_runtime=0, sched_deadline=0, sched_period=0}, 0) = 0
```

I couldn't find the syscall in glibc or the structure in sched.h on my system for some reason, so I had to include the structure and the syscall definition. I don't know a lot about this, so this function may be lower-level than needed, and a higher-level call could do what you want more easily, but this reflects exactly what chrt is doing.